# Random not that random

Tags: c#, .net, random

I am using Random to generate a sequence of random number. I am constructing the random object just once and then inside the loop generating the random values (300 of them). The problem is that once I get all the values and do a sort on them I realize that some of them are equal and/or sequential: I am generating numbers from 0 to 50000.

This is my script:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int n=0; n < 300; n++)
{
    int RndNumber = rnd.Next(0, 50000);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3);
}
```

Can someone have a clue on why this is happening, and how can I improve this to make it more random?

Comment: You need to be specific about how you define "more random"

Comment: why are you sorting random numbers? doesn't that defeat the purpose of generating random numbers?

Comment: Could the problem be with sorting?

Comment: I'm no mathematician, but it seems to me that it would be highly unlikely that, after sorting a list of 300 random numbers between 0 and 50000, at least a couple of them wouldn't be equal or sequential.

Comment: Why are you sorting the random values? Is it just to test their distribution? This might have something to do with the [Birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Collision_counting)

Comment: Do you expect the numbers to be equally spaced across the range - 10, 110, 210, 310, etc?  That seems far less random.

Comment: you need a much bigger sample set to really evaluate the distribution

Comment: Hmmm, by my back of the envelope calculation: the chance that a pair of numbers in that range would be equal is 1 in 50000 and there are almost 45000 pairs in a set of 300 numbers so it's quite likely that there will be some matches.

Comment: Thanks to all your value feedback. My question solved by Jason and Dan Tao. I sort the numbers so that i can see the 'quality' of the random number i got.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As an explanation of *why* you're seeing the occasional duplicate, [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858790/random-not-that-random/4858840#4858840) is right on.

If what you *want* is 300 distinct random numbers, what about something like this?

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetRandoms(int min, int max)
{
    var rand = new Random();
    while (true)
    {
        yield return rand.Next(min, max);
    }
}

var distinctRandoms = GetRandoms(0, 50000).Distinct().Take(300);
```

Comment: Yup it gives distinct number but it still have conjunction numbers, this is due to the Birthday paradox I believe. This seems to be fulfilling what i need to do. Thanks Dan Tao

Comment: Keep in mind that by forcing distinction, you are in fact harming the "Randomness" - the distribution is no longer (pseudo) uniform.

Comment: @bavaza: Not sure if that comment is aimed at me or the OP, but I think the OP does not actually want true *randomness*; otherwise he wouldn't be asking this question. Of course you're correct that eliminating duplicates compromises the randomness of the data, just as sorting does.

Comment: @Dan: It was aimed at the OP and other SO junkies out there. I decided  to add it because I often found that people tend to abuse statistics. Anyways, thanks for the answer :-).

Comment: perfect though for psuedo random lists thanks DanTao

Answer (score 21):

So this is the birthday paradox<sup>*</sup>. When you draw 300 numbers from 50000 the approximate probability that at least two of them are equal is

```
p(300) = 1 - exp(-300 * 300 / (2 * 50000))
       = 0.59
```

(I could work out the exact probability but I'm lazy<sup>!</sup>.)

So, chances are more likely than not that you'll have a collision. Sequential is even more likely (now you don't need a collision, you just need `n - 1` and `n` or `n` and `n + 1` to be hit for some `n`).

Random is fickle.

<sup>*</sup>: In case you're not familiar with it, it says that if you have twenty-three people in a room, it is more likely than not that at least two people in the room share the same birthday.

<sup>!</sup>: Okay, I worked it out. It's 0.5953830515549951746819986449....

Answer (score 13):

**Research:**

If you use the constructor without parameters `new Random()` the seed is depending on the current servertime.

> Random(): "Initializes a new instance of the Random class, using a time-dependent"
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

So, if I try it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   Random ran = new Random();
   Console.WriteLine(ran.Next(50001));
}
```

I only get 3 different numbers about 300 times within a thousand calls! Not that random...

Setting the seed in the constructor `new Random(0)` returns a fix serie of numbers.

e.g. `new Random(0).Next(50)` **always!** returns 36. Try it yourself, if you don't trust me;

What we need for "real" random numbers is a changing seed, that's independent of time.

I'm using Hashcode of changing values:

e.g. `Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()` or `DateTime.Now.GetHashCode()`

---

**Result:**

```
Random ran = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{       
   Console.WriteLine(ran.Next(50001));
}
```

or (for better performance):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
     int val = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode() % 50001;
     val = val > 0 ? val : -val;
     Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

PS: The maximum of the Next(max)-method is always max - 1;

-> ran.Next(11) can return 0,1,2,...,8,9,10.  Not 11!

Comment: `DateTime.Now.GetHashCode()` is no better than the default seed.

Comment: +1 This was "random" enough for my liking :) No clumps of numbers when I tried to generate 2000 of them.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Your right. I don't know exactly if the default constructor of Random uses the DateTimes hashcode or milliseconds or whatever, but it ain't random at all

Comment: I love it, a very simple and modular solution

Comment: @Bahamut Do you realize that it wasn't your new seed value that fixed it, it was the fact that you moved the initialization of the `Random` instance out of the loop? Experiments are most effective when only one variable changes between trials.