# String, random, interesting behavior

Tags: c#, .net, random, stringbuilder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why does this method return the same random string each time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807892/why-does-this-method-return-the-same-random-string-each-time)
>   [Random not that random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858790/random-not-that-random)

I have weird behavior in this code.

```
public void InitPopulation()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PopSize; i++)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var random = new Random();

        for (int j = 0; j < Target.Length; j++)
        {
            builder.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65))));
        }

                        vector.Add(new GaStruct() { Fitness = 0, StrValue = builder.ToString().ToLower() });
        builder.Clear();
    }
}
```

This code gives me 5 absolutely identical strings!

If I add the `Thread.Sleep` like this:

```
public void InitPopulation()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < PopSize; i++)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        var random = new Random();

        for (int j = 0; j < Target.Length; j++)
        {
            builder.Append(Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65))));
        }

        **System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);**
        vector.Add(new GaStruct() { Fitness = 0, StrValue = builder.ToString().ToLower() });
        builder.Clear();
    }
}
```

everything is okay, all strings are random.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858790/random-not-that-random  I ran into this myself.  To get around it, declare the Random outside of the loop.

Comment: Also read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx